# Characters that can be present in the ROWID Oracle

Tags: oracle11g, rowid

I need to know what are the characters can come in `ROWID Psudocolumn` in Oracle

I Have `MIN(ROWID)` as `AABy9CAAEAAACULAAA` and `MAX(ROWID)` as `AABy9CABgAAKiB/AA4`

Until now I thought that only alphanumeric will be present in the `ROWID` values
but as you can see in the `MAX(ROWID)` there is a special character.

I need to know what are the other character may exist in the `ROWID`

Thank you

Comment: Why do you need to know this?

Comment: basically these are hexadecimal numbers.

Comment: There is 4 trillion record present in a table and I intend to divide it into small chunks  through ROWID

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Oracle [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements001.htm#i46148):

> Extended rowids are stored as base 64 values that can contain the characters A-Z, a-z, 0-9, and the plus sign (+) and forward slash (/). Extended rowids are not available directly.

So other than basic alphanumeric characters, the only "special" characters are the plus sign and forward slash.

Note that prior to Oracle version 8 the `rowid` had a different format, whose details can be seen at the same documentation link.